# How to update particular value of child in Firebase DB

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data). Following is my code for update:

```
func updateDealResultToServer(key:String,dealResult : String)
{

    let post = ["dealResul": dealResult]
    let childUpdates =
        ["/komal_xyz/\(key)": post
        ]

    rootRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

}
```

This Is my Firebase database structure:
[image]

I want to only change the value for `dealResult`. Whenever I try to run above code for particular child node like `1473670100726`, other value except `dealResul` is deleted.

Comment: @omal Kamble:when i remove value from listing from one device that value remove from another device at same time ?so how that happen ? please explain for android. i dont understand how work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Updating values at a particular node in Firebase Realtime Database, use:-

- You can either use **`runTransactionBlock:`**

  ```
    func updateTotalNoOfPost(completionBlock : (() -> Void)){


  let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("komal_kyz").child(your_AuroID).child("dealResul")

  prntRef.runTransactionBlock({ (resul) -> FIRTransactionResult in
      if let dealResul_Initial = resul.value as? Int{

          //resul.value = dealResul_Initial + 1
          //Or HowSoEver you want to update your dealResul. 
           return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(resul)
      }else{

          return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(resul)

      }
      }, andCompletionBlock: {(error,completion,snap) in

              print(error?.localizedDescription)
              print(completion)
              print(snap)
          if !completion {

             print("Couldn't Update the node")
          }else{

              completionBlock()
          }
      })

   }
  ```

  While calling this function:-

  ```
  updateTotalNoOfPost{
         print("Updated")
        }
  ```
- **Or** just call **`updateValues`**

  ```
      let prntRef  = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("komal_kyz").child(your_AuroID)
      prntRef.updateChildValues(["dealResul":dealResult])
  ```

PS:- Prefer using **`runTransactionBlock:`** instead of **`.updateChildValues`** if you only want to increment a particular node. Also read this: -https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458044/6297658

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `setValue` for single child updates (keep in mind that I am using Swift 3, slight syntax changes may apply but you should be fine):

```
rootRef.child("komal_kyz").child(key).setValue(["dealResul":dealResult])
```

Comment: Is there a reason why using `setValue` is better?

Answer (score 1):

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child("childKey").updateChildValues(["childKeyForUpdate": "NewData"])
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you provide some details?

Comment: firebase is a database which is used for implement chatting functionality in your application , firebase provide socket programming.
if you want to update value of any selected chilled then this code help-full for you in which "user" is a your table name on firebaseDataBase and "childKey" is a chilled of user table and "childKeyForUpdate" is your selected key for update and the "NewData" id your latest data for replace to old