# Firebase: What's the correct way to update values?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If my database structure is like this: [image]

and I have this:

```
    ref = Database.database().reference().child(passUserID)

    ref?.child("wins").updateChildValues("wins": numerator)
```

where numerator = (games played beforehand) + (games played after logging in), for the second statement it is giving me an error in the expression that I don't know how to fix.

Also if I try to do this instead:

```
ref?.child("wins").setValue(numerator)
```

it messes up my data bad and gives a bad instruction error.

Answer (score 1):

The `updateChildValues` method takes a `Dictionary`. So you just need to call the method with a dictionary containing the key-value pairs you want to update, i.e.

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child(passUserID)

ref?.updateChildValues(["wins": numerator])
```

For more on how to read/write data to firebase realtime database, refer to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

If you use .setValue triggers only in the beginning. Instead of .setValue use updateChildValues(.values/.childAdded/.childRemoved etc..) to update the values inside your tree. It will be executed whenever changes occurs to your node.

[How to update particular value of child in Firebase DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462410/how-to-update-particular-value-of-child-in-firebase-db)