# How to achieve this structure in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How to have a main child "subscribers" and then inside it a child with an users's uid and then all the uids of users who have subscribed to that user.
This way I would store all subscribers of a user and I could easily retrieve them if needed.

```
{
  "subscribers": {
    "uid1": {
      "uid4": true,
      "uid7": true,
      "uid3": true
    },
    "uid15": { 
      "uid3": true,
      "uid9": true,
      "uid17": true
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't want to use push() because it generates its own key and if I use setValue() on uid1, then it deletes all its children and ads only the new one, which is also not good. So I want to be able to add and remove subscribers for a certain uid.

**SOLUTION:**

In my case I was targeting the Android platform, so Java. The solution is based on Dravidian's comment using **updateChildren()**. Thank you Dravidian.

```
// ADD SUBSCRIBER
        String key = uid; // the uid of the user we want to subscribe to
        HashMap<String, Object> subscriber = new HashMap<>();
        subscriber.put(subscriberUid, true);
    mDatabase.child("subscriptions").child(key).
            updateChildren(subscriber, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed");
                }
            });

// REMOVE SUBSCRIBER
    mDatabase.child("subscriptions").child(key).child(subscriberUid).removeValue();


// RETRIEVE SUBSCRIBER
    mDatabase.child("subscriptions").child(key).
            orderByChild(subscriberUid).limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Datasnapshot exists: " + dataSnapshot.exists());

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "User is subscribed");

                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "User is not subscribed");

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39458044/6297658

Comment: What platform are you targeting? And did you try anything already? Seeing what you tried/where are stuck will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your interest. Dravidian's suggestion helped me. I wrote the solution I have adopted.