# Firebase like system inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I created like system into my tableview cell. However it has problems.

1. If I like one thing, every 7th cell is getting like also, why? Is there something with reusableCell?
2. What is the best approach doing it, am I doing it totally wrong?

This is the like button system:

```
cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    func tapped(sender: DOFavoriteButton) {
            if sender.isSelected {
                // deselect
                sender.deselect()//+1 like
            } else {
                // select with animation
                sender.select()//-1 like 
            }
        }
```

And this is my likeSystem function:

```
func likeSystem(sender: DOFavoriteButton, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if sender.isSelected {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "snusProductsCell", for: indexPath) as! SnusProductTableViewCell
        self.databaseRef.child("Snuses").child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) -> FIRTransactionResult in
            if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                var stars : Dictionary<String, Bool>
                stars = post["hasLiked"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
                var starCount = post["likes"] as? Int ?? 0
                if let _ = stars[uid] {
                    // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                    starCount -= 1
                    stars.removeValue(forKey: uid)

                } else {
                    // Star the post and add self to stars
                    starCount += 1

                    stars[uid] = true
                    sender.deselect()
                }
                post["hasLiked"] = starCount as AnyObject?
                post["likes"] = stars as AnyObject?

                // Set value and report transaction success
                currentData.value = post

                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        }else{
            sender.select()
        }
    }
```

My brain is crashing ATM.. Do not know how to continue. Please lead me back to the track.

This is my Structure:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39492396/6297658

Comment: This is the same code as in [your previous question]( http://stackoverflow.com/q/39937930). Having multiple questions open with the exact same code is typically a sign that you should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to isolate the problem.

Comment: dude any news on your question?

Comment: I actually were stuck with indexPath.rows because I had to use those outside of tableview functions so I gave up. But I have plan to read your question and accept it today :)

Comment: ooooookay and how did that work out? :P

Comment: Doing it right now :)

Comment: And how did this work? ;) Please remember that people are trying to help you by investing their own time. In exchange for upvotes and "as answered checks".

Comment: bro? the question is still open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my functions and work around to handle likes:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    var liked = 0
    var likes: [String] = []
    var likeCounter = 0

    func readLikeStatus() {
        if liked == 0 {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unlike"), forState: .Normal)
            likeButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            likeLabel.text = "\(likeCounter) Likes"

        } else {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), forState: .Normal)
            likeButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            likeLabel.text = "\(likeCounter) Likes"
        }           
    }

    @IBAction func likeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if liked == 0 {

            likeTweet()
            liked = 1
            likeCounter = likeCounter + 1
            readLikeStatus()

        } else if liked == 1 {

            unlikeTweet()
            liked = 0
            likeCounter = likeCounter - 1
            readLikeStatus()

        }
    }

    func likeTweet() {
        let userID = [backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId: backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId]
        let usersRef = firebase.child("DeejayTweets").child(passedDJ.objectId).child(tweetID).child("likes")
        usersRef.updateChildValues(userID)
    }

    func unlikeTweet() {
        let userID = backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId
        let usersRef = firebase.child("DeejayTweets").child(passedDJ.objectId).child(tweetID).child("likes")
        usersRef.child(userID).removeValue()
    }

    func bindData(post: Tweet, indexPath: NSIndexPath, commentCount: NSMutableDictionary, avatare: NSMutableDictionary) {
        likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unlike"), forState: .Normal)
        likeButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
        liked = 0

        setLike(post, indexPath: indexPath, commentCount: commentCount, avatare: avatare)
     }

     func setLike(post: Tweet, indexPath: NSIndexPath, commentCount: NSMutableDictionary, avatare: NSMutableDictionary) {

        //SET IF TWEET IS LIKED
        if post.likes.contains(backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId) {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), forState: .Normal)
            likeButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            liked = 1
         }

         //SET LIKE COUNTER


         if post.likes.count == 1 {
            likeLabel.text = "0 Likes"
            likeCounter = 0
         } else if post.likes.count == 1 {
            likeLabel.text = "\(post.likes.count - 1) Like"
            likeCounter = 1
         } else {
            likeLabel.text = "\(post.likes.count - 1) Likes"
            likeCounter = 1
        }
     }
```

To call everything:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController.... {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
            let post = tweets[indexPath.row]

            cell.bindData(post, indexPath: indexPath, commentCount: commentCount, avatare: avatare)

            return cell
    }
```

And in my firebase I handle everything like this:

[image]

I'm not saying, that this is the world's best practise, but it is working and might give you the idea of how to handle this.

Comment: Can you say, why [backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId: backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId] is in array? And is the passedDJ.objectId post id?

Comment: so i have value and key the id, i wanted it like that. u could also put name:id

Comment: I have this JSON struct like on image. So it should be key?

Comment: all in needed for my likes is to save the "liker" as array of `[key:id and value:id]` that way i can access it the fastest. i can count the amount of likers and i can have a where clause to get all the users for ids by "allvalues"

Comment: May I ask you one thing. Why you did struct like this for posts? Like storing post inside UID? Is there some purpose for later on?

Comment: sure, ask whatever. i'm not sure about your question. what you exactly want to know. but i'm using a struct for literally everything. i'm not using NSDictionary anymore. to make sure, that the data is not optional and not nil

Comment: i have a struct for Tweet, User, Track, etc etc. everywhere, where i create o model of something.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the JSON Struct.

Comment: i see. because in that case, it's like the user feed on facebook. you have a useraccount. you go on a profile. user's feed gets loaded. that way i query for the user and receive all the posts

Comment: userID is fixed. postID is autoID.

Comment: Ohh okay. So the JSON struct I have, then it is not possible to see other user profile?

Comment: well. if this is the root of your json struct, how dow do you get the tweet for a certain person. if for example you only want to receive the posts of User David?

Comment: Oh I see.. In this case I should make one more child: UID  and store posts under that?

Comment: like said. how else do you want to `filter` for posts by user?

Comment: I actually didn't think that until now :D

Comment: But how in your case you are able to query all "tweets"? not just specific user ones? using: queryOrdered(byChild: "tweets")?

Comment: And documentation says not to do like you are doing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: what is the problem? in that case i just query the whole DeejayTweets tree and unpack the dictionary in my app

Comment: i then just query the SAME way, but without the .child of userID

Comment: i then just have to call the .allValues. so i get all the tweets of all the userID keys

Comment: and i haven't read the documentation and my way is working for a couple of thousand users so far...