# How to append without unique auto id firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, append, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append data to my database, everytime a user is clicking a like button, if the user hasn't already clicked it. The problem is, when I am appending to the `likesForPost`, a unique id is showing. How can I get rid of that? Otherwise it is not possible for me to check if the user has already clicked the button?

Here is my firebase structure:
[image]

It is the green parts that are unique id, the black zones under the unique id are the user id, that I want to be able to check if has already clicked the button.

This is my code for appending to `likesForPost`

```
let quoteString = [userId: true]
                let refPhotos = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost")
                let refBase54 = refPhotos.childByAutoId()
                refBase54.setValue(quoteString)
```

Hope you guys can help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :-

```
let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost")
prntRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

    if let favDict = snap.value as? NSMutableDictionary{
        favDict.setObject("true",forKey : uid)
        prntRef.setValue(favDict) 
    } else {
        prntRef.setValue(["true":uid])
    }
})
```

Or **But this is just a HACK!**

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").updateChildValues(quoteString)
```

For more options check:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458044/6297658

Comment: The problem could be fixed if there was some way to get the unique auto id, firebase is creating?

Comment: Doesnt matter until your uid doesn't exist in the dictionary key, it will act as appending the values

Comment: Great! Do you also know how to log out of facebook, so I can try another account in the simulator? (I have a logout button, but when I press log in again, it is using the same account)